# play video in Webview on Floating window play only sound

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, html5-video

I'm trying to implements a webview in a floating window like this library [Standout](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) ,everything work well but I get only 1 error is when i play a video in internet, it only play the sound , the screen is black. I have set

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUEaK.png <= screenshot. 
it's only plays sound without video.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: @Siddharth : Logcat not show any error, the MediaPlayer native is playing but I hear only sound, video is black.

Comment: Are you able to run video in normal videoview or browser?

Comment: which device are you using for testing ?

Comment: It's play normally in my main browser, but in Floating window (one feature of my browser) it gets this error. My device is LG G Pro

Comment: I'm just add the screenshot for my Question!

Comment: Have you enabled hardware acceleration for the webview?

Comment: @ksasq I've already add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" , but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED` flag when add WebView into WindowManager